# Is there any setTimeout equivalent in JSFL

Tags: flash, jsfl, flash-cc

I've created a JSFL code which retrieves the position, width and height of all the elements and write them in a JSON file. Its absolutely working fine on some Flash files.

I observed that it sometime fails on the heavy files. And sometime it never completes or gives any error. Flash stays in the work in progress state.

I think the issues might be the FOR loop. I'm using for loop to read the frames, layers and the elements to get their property. So its king of recursive going on which hangs sometime.

Therefore I was wandering if there is any method like setTimeout I can use that, which at least will not hang. And more over I can show a progress on the action.

Please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

The best way to manipulate JSFL using SWF.

[See here](http://www.sitepoint.com/flash-panels/)